# ExtJS grid Panel Paging toolbar not showing required number of records per page

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I am new to extJS and I am trying to show 8[a random number] records in a grid panel and am also using paging toolbar to show 4 records per page but it shows 8 records in one page only.

```
var myData = [
    ['3m Co', 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American International Group, Inc.', 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['AT&T Inc.', 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Boeing Co.', 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Caterpillar Inc.', 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Citigroup, Inc.', 49.37, 0.02, 0.04, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.', 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, '9/1 12:00am']
];

var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    totalProperty: 8,
    autoLoad: {
        params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: 4
        }
    },
    fields: [{
        name: 'company'
    }, {
        name: 'price',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'change',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'pctChange',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'lastChange',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'
    }]
});

store.loadData(myData);

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        id: 'company',
        header: "Company",
        width: 160,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'company'
    }, {
        header: "Price",
        width: 75,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: 'usMoney',
        dataIndex: 'price'
    }, {
        header: "Change",
        width: 75,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: change,
        dataIndex: 'change'
    }, {
        header: "% Change",
        width: 75,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: pctChange,
        dataIndex: 'pctChange'
    }, {
        header: "Last Updated",
        width: 85,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
        dataIndex: 'lastChange'
    }],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'company',
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Array Grid',

    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store: store,
        pageSize: 4,
        displayInfo: true
    }),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the store.loadData() call you should be calling the .load() function on the store and passing in an object with arguments specifying your maximum page size.

check out the examples on this page http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.PagingToolbar

EDIT: Another option is to do the following. Call the .loadData() and after you have instantiated your grid, you can call

```
grid.store.load({params:{start: 0, limit: 4}});
```

Comment: I have ammended the answer with another alternative :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But It doesn't really help me. When I use .load() and give data: myData in config. Nothing shows up. Firebug says this.proxy is undefined. Please Help!

Comment: @Anna: What version of extJs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Ext.ux.data.PagingStore` for client side paging.
Try something like this:

```
var store = new Ext.ux.data.PagingStore({
    reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
        fields: [
                 {name: 'company'},
                 {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
                 {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
                 {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
                 {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
                ],
    }),
    totalProperty : 8,
    autoLoad:{
        params:{start:0, limit:4}
    },
    data: myData
});
```

You may need to tweak this a bit as I have not tested it.
I have it working with a `JsonReader` fetching records from the server.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again! I have done some research and changed a code a bit. But now I am getting this.proxy undefined. Please help me out- you can see my code: http://codepad.org/qbRs1cbD

Comment: @Anna: beacause you are using the autoLoad config property the store expects to have a proxy with a defined url to send the params start and limit to.

Comment: Actually I used proxy config in the store. Without it "No"